# Sum values by date range in multiple columns

Tags: oracle, date-range

I need to sum value by date range in multiple columns. Every date range is one week of a month. It can be shorter than 7 days if it is the start of the month or the end of the month.
For example, I have dates for February:

```
my_user        my_date        my_value
A              01.02.2019     100
A              02.02.2019     150
B              01.02.2019     90
Z              28.02.2019     120
```

How can I have in date range format such as below?

```
my_user   01/02-03/02   04/02-10/02   11/02-17/02  18/02-24/02  25/02-28/02
A              250      0             0            0            0 
B              90       0             0            0            0 
Z              0        0             0            0            120
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
select *
  from (
    select to_char(dt, 'iw') - to_char(trunc(dt, 'month'), 'iw') + 1 wk, usr, val from t)
  pivot (sum(val) for wk in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e30bb33557c526deb0d5a8a2a4364e55)</sup>**

```
USR          1          2          3          4          5          6
--- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
A          250                                             
B                                            90            
Z                                                      120
```

Header numbers are the weeks of month. Maximum may be 6 if month starts at the end of the week and is longer than 28 days.

Similiar way you can find first and last day of each week if needed, but you can't put them as headers, or at least not easily.

---

**Edit:**

> it is possible to define certain date range with pivot, simple as two
>   dates? For example, I need to sum values from 5 December 2018 to 4
>   January 2019, 5 January 2019 to 4 February 2019, 5 March 2019 to 4
>   April 2019

Yes. Everything depends on how we count first and next weeks. Here:

```
to_char(dt, 'iw') - to_char(trunc(dt, 'month'), 'iw') + 1
```

i am subtracting week in year for given date and week in year of first day in month for this date. You can simply replace this second value with your starting date, either by hardcoding it in your query or by sending parameter to query or finding minimum date at first in a subquery:

```
(to_char(dt, 'iw') - to_char(date '2019-03-05', 'iw')) + 1
```

or

```
(to_char(dt, 'iw') - to_char((select min(dt) from data), 'iw')) + 1
```

---

**Edit 2:**

There is one problem however. When user defined period contains two or more years. `to_date(..., 'iw')` works fine for one year, but for two we get values 51, 52, 01, 02... We have to deal with this somehow, for instance like here:

```
with t(dt1, dt2) as (select date '2018-12-16', date '2019-01-15' from dual)
select min(dt) mnd, max(dt) mxd, iw, row_number() over (order by min(dt)) rn
  from (select dt1 + level - 1 dt, to_char(dt1 + level - 1, 'iw') iw
          from t connect by level -1 <= dt2 - dt1)
  group by iw
```

which gives us:

```
MND         MXD         IW         RN
----------- ----------- -- ----------
2018-12-16  2018-12-16  50          1
2018-12-17  2018-12-23  51          2
2018-12-24  2018-12-30  52          3
2018-12-31  2019-01-06  01          4
2019-01-07  2019-01-13  02          5
2019-01-14  2019-01-15  03          6
```

In first line we have user defined date ranges. Then I did hierarchical query looping through all dates in range assigning `week`, then grouped by this week, found start and end dates for each week and assigned row number `rn` which can be further used by pivot.

You can now simply join your input data with this query, let's name it `weeks`:

```
from data join weeks on dt between mnd and mxd
```

and make pivot. But for longer periods you have to find how many weeks there can be and specify them in pivot clause `in (1, 2, 3, 4...)`. You can also add aliases if you need:

```
pivot ... for rn in (1 week01, 2 week02... 12 week12)
```

There is no simply way to avoid listing them manually. If you need it please look for `oracle dynamic pivot` in SO, there where hundreds similiar questions already. ;-)

Comment: Thanks. It is great works in one month. Although, could you tell me, please,  it is possible to define certain date range with pivot, simple as two dates? For example, I need to sum values from 5 December 2018 to 4 January 2019, 5 January 2019 to 4 February 2019, 5 March 2019 to 4 April 2019